# Powerbi Gateway - load-balancing

Tags: powerbi, gateway, onpremises-gateway

We are using today a gateway powerbi to collect data from our core-it infra to the powerbi service. Till today it's working fine but we only have one server and we are looking for a way to add an extra gateway in order to have a setup allowing to do load-balancing between those two gateways.

Does someone of you already do such thing ? 
Any advice ?

Comment: The answer is just a google away https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-high-availability-clusters#load-balance-across-gateways-in-a-cluster

Comment: Yes, I've read it but I've got some questions. if I understand correctly, the cluster is created by default and we just add servers to the cluster? Are the already created "connections" automatically copied to the new server?

Comment: Don't leave us in suspense.

Comment: and , can I have different version of the gateway installed on the same cluster ? :)

Comment: Those are two excellent questions. I don't know the answer but I've posted a document request on that site.

Comment: We will do some test in the coming weeks on a dedicated labo just to confirm the behavior. I will post here the results